# JButton added, but not visible

Tags: java, swing, panel, jbutton, paintcomponent

I want to create a Pong game in Java. I draw all my stuff with my paintComponent method. In this method i call another method "initBall". This method draw the ball at the start position.  When i died, I want to draw my ball at the init position again and i want to add a button at the center of my panel that say " Press escape to continue " and then the ball start moving. The problem is that my button is not visible.

Please help me  :)

Here is my code :

```
public class PlayPanel extends JPanel implements ConstantesCommunes {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int posX;
    private int posY;

    private boolean newBall = true;

    private JPanel pan_WestZone = new JPanel();
    private JPanel pan_EastZone = new JPanel();

    private JButton but_Escape  = new JButton("Press escape to continue !");

    Graphics2D graphics2d;

    /*
     * Constructeur de classe : PlayPanel.java
     */
    // ==============================================
    public PlayPanel() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        pan_WestZone.setPreferredSize(WESTPANEL_SIZE);
        pan_EastZone.setPreferredSize(EASTPANEL_SIZE);

        pan_WestZone.setBackground(ZONE_COLOR);
        pan_EastZone.setBackground(ZONE_COLOR);

        add(pan_WestZone, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(pan_EastZone, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    /*
     * Ajouter la balle sur la surface de jeux
     */
    // ==============================================
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        posX = SCREEN_WIDTH / 2;

        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setColor(Color.ORANGE);

        initBall(g2);

        // trait épais
        g2.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

        g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(10));
        g2.drawLine((SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - 5, SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2) - 5, 0);
    }

    /*
     * Initialiser la balle lorsqu'un joueur perd
     */
    // ==============================================
    private void initBall(Graphics2D graphics2d) {      

        but_Escape.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

        Graphics2D g2 = graphics2d;
        g2.fillOval(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT);

        // The problem is here 
        add(but_Escape);
    }
```

thanks

Comment: _never-ever_ change the state of the component while painting! Instead, change the state (triggered by whatever event), then trigger a re/paint/validate if needed

Comment: @kleopatra : Ahha, yeah I forgot to catch that thingy :( , that's a good insight again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding button inside your `inItBall(...)` simply `revalidate()` your `JPanel`, as

```
private void initBall(Graphics2D graphics2d) 
{      
    but_Escape.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

    Graphics2D g2 = graphics2d;
    g2.fillOval(SCREEN_WIDTH / 2, 0, BALL_WIDTH, BALL_HEIGHT);

    // The problem is here 
    add(but_Escape);
    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: @MTHeadss : Or you can call `repaint()` after `revalidate()`, to make that `JButton` appear on the `JPanel`, if `revalidate()` alone won't help.

Comment: Hehe, You are MOST Welcome and Keep Smiling :-)

Comment: would be correct - except that the OP calls init from inside paintComponent (see my comment to the question @MTHeadss)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `setVisible(true);`.